# Count number of Classes and Methods with Comments

Tags: java, comments, javadoc, doxygen

Trying to find a way to count the Number of Java Classes, and methods that either have comments or need comments.  We are trying to document all our code but its gonna take a while and we would like to post metrics on how far along we are.  We are using Doxygen to convert Javadoc to webpages.  I haven't found a way yet with Doxygen but doesn't mean its not there.

Comment: Why not just write a program that recursively looks for files, create a list of classes and look for comments before 'class' and just set a boolean if that is found.  What requirements do you have to a class to have a comment?  Do you just require /** ... */ ? Or some actual text?

Comment: In the Linux/Unix world, you might be able to pull that off with `find` and `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on all the warnings in Doxygen, and then get a line count of the log file.

Comment: Not sure I see which flags to turn on... can you be more specific?

Comment: `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES` `WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES` `WARN_NO_PARAMDOC = YES` and set `WARN_LOGFILE` to any valid filename.

Comment: I tried this and I get a few lines of errors in comments but I get 0 lines of undocumented.  Using eclipse Doxygen version 1.8.*, bu when I run it in Doxygen gui+ provided I do get results...So word of warning use the GUI not Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I've used [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org/model.html) in the past for source code analysis. It parses java sources into a [nice model](http://qdox.codehaus.org/apidocs/com/thoughtworks/qdox/model/JavaClass.html) for gathering statistics / automated code generation etc.

Comment: Kinda of cool but lots of hand coding more than I would like.  Any more out of the box solutions.

Comment: Agreed... but it does give you total control